# generate JavaDocs Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, javadoc

Is there any way to generate JavaDoc in Android Studio in a similar way it's done in Eclipse where I just go to Project --> Generate Java Docs ? I mean export it as HTML page. I cannot find a similar option in Android Studio, I searched multiple  posts and I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When a project is open go to **Tools > Generate JavaDoc** .

Comment: Is there a way to extract the docs into external for the project file?

Comment: what do you mean by external exactly ?

Comment: I want to extract all my javadoc comments into external file.

Comment: Android studio automatically generates docs as html files only. There is a whole bunch of options there for what you what to include in your generated javadoc but you cannot export it in a custom way (like in a single file) as javadocs are generated based on the classes of your project.

Comment: Thanks, I was supposing so...I can write a gradle task or plain java to do that. I just didn't want to.